# Typescript, automatically infer type from object keys

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to declare an interface for a Select component that can be a multiple or single items select.

```js
interface MySelect<T extends boolean> {
    multi: T, // Is this a multiple items select
    onChange: (item: T extends true ? string[]: string) => void // the onChange signature differs according to T
}
```

It works but I have to explicitly sets the generic type T:

```
const mySelect: MySelect<true> = { // Here
    multi: true, // And here
    onChange: (items) => {}
}
```

I would like to know if it's possible to have TS automatically infer T from the "multi" value:

```
const mySelect: MySelect = {
    multi: true, // multi is true so T is true
    onChange: (items) => {}
}
```

Important update: I want "multiple" to be optional (it would default to false if key is missing or undefined)

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67048097/typescript-interface-required-property-based-on-another-property

Comment: True though I had one specific requirement I forgot to mention: [see my comment on your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67372053/typescript-automatically-infer-type-from-object-keys?noredirect=1#comment119083720_67372139)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've updated your question to say that `multi` should be optional (default false). That rules out a discriminated union (the previous answer under the horizontal line below).

I think I'd use two interfaces you union together, and (if necessary) a base interface for the things they have in common. You'll probably want type guard functions for when you need to know the type of the select.

```typescript
// Things all MySelects have in common (if you have anything other than `onChange`)
interface MySelectBase {
    name: string;
}
// A single-select version of MySelect
interface MySingleSelect extends MySelectBase {
    multi?: false;
    onChange: (item: string) => void;
}
// A multi-select version of MySelect
interface MyMultiSelect extends MySelectBase {
    multi: true;
    onChange: (items: string[]) => void;
}
// The unified type
type MySelect = MySingleSelect | MyMultiSelect;

// Type guard function to see whether it's a single select
const isSingleSelect = (select: MySelect): select is MySingleSelect => {
    return !select.multi; // !undefined and !false are both true
};

// Type guard function to see whether it's a multi select
const isMultiSelect = (select: MySelect): select is MyMultiSelect => {
    return !!select.multi; // !!undefined and !!true are both true
};
```

Examples of creation:

```typescript
const single: MySingleSelect = {
    name: "some-single-select-field",
    onChange : (item) => { console.log(item); }
};

const multi: MyMultiSelect = {
    multi: true,
    name: "some-multi-select-field",
    onChange : (items) => { console.log(items); }
};
```

Example of using `MySelect` (the combined interface):

```
const useMySelect = (select: MySelect) => {
    // No need for a guard on anything but `onChange`
    console.log(select.name);
    // `onChange` will be a union type until/unless you use a type guard
    const onChange = select.onChange;
    //    ^^^^^^^^−−−−−−−−−− type is `((item: string) => void) | ((items: string[]) => void)`
    if (isSingleSelect(select)) {
        // It's a MySingleSelect
        const onChange = select.onChange;
        //    ^^^^^^^^−−−−−−−−−− type is `(item: string) => void`
    } else {
        // It's a MyMultiSelect
        const onChange = select.onChange;
        //    ^^^^^^^^−−−−−−−−−− type is `(items: string[]) => void`
    }
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBUAsEsDsHMDOoCGAbNoCyBPAygKZoEDGALspCgG4GhygkD2Ati07KABTQBmoOJgFdQVWqlg4yMBKCbSCAJ1DSUnAAYcAwlQQF1ASgBQcMkt4oSdXIWLkAQikR0A3kdAfQsFCwIAuUEQyRTh4AG4jAF8jEFAAQUDQ4gBaZzsyUFpFRGgOOX4bIlIyE1gzRQsrbHwkglti0AIADzNYABNkQvTHZ1A3T1AWITQyaAB+AIs0ZwiB7V14f25oMxYAoJCEA1AAXgA+TKZoNojo2IShkehUovJMpRy8pgL8W5LTc0trHCxh0fq7s1Wh1qgCyD1XO5PJdRgFgkICLNPPM1IsAjxVoh1sFQgBtAC6232h2OpxiYCgdCEsD40AIbRUOAADgQjGRmd8wbtQbUuQAfaq-K5giLkiAc0DwIQoRQM3jU8i5ThkJiBAh0ADukAICmUKwA5MgUIkEMQ1ekjMxYEF6Ig8Ly3tyuGligEusUDOtHdBOjVTXVHcT+p5FDqhIpOABCF3kAB0MOgYVAsUj1LaBF4cHpEgZkamvRldAARvJICpFAioqLYuAJVKZXKFaM8iq1Zrtbr6GRDahBn9oObipaODafUL-oHuDGyG7XulPYO7j7Bf2uUGoR5Q2Rw1Ho294-2kynU+0M1mGWpc5H4XRC6AS9Jy5XItWwDt36AAKJNHxM4jIZ5GFDFBm1gPwjGHa0Mhyf1Z3tf01z6DcvB8JYACJEFYAhUlqG50mSTMiDaNCABpkJRPRQHRFYCBYIkDhcRgRyYYhYzQJh4AxWiDCTaIXwgq0bQTWdx2gRDgw8YSnwIMiBm8XwAgwrDkgTPDigIuk0GI2TkVgHRUToajMXovomOtFiCDYjiuJYRAeNAPjX12D9v1-M1AKEGD4FBN5wMgm1PIId07h2KdfJ8+ddgY5DYgAOVVWB1TlJhlGNetZTkTg1CkGRvKLIQMk0PSFn0ZDBIsqzOOnWN5IIHiyuY1j2Kq-cE3qgZYiK-S9HUUANWgDB71vUBqSVRkWRGsoBuAal-2QQQREC3t2Qm9K2gaqDMu6xZuWqijFiRDxYk8AA9M7zrOwAkImum7bvGuhl3ULgbOxTZ4BM6gjjabYBWemjbNevFCSiklvvUZC+GWO0HXSZ03gMbYJIGZMwAASW7I0eQQt5kIGQSMn2uhQr24qDMO5Hjo8C6Ltu2nLvu21QCe-7Aa2EHPuOcGBkiRppkhZHPFidGe2NXBRLBXHPHxraSt2-dCfJjqwFO6mrrpm6GcemysUCHEEAJD6vq5zxHKAA)

---

This is the original answer for folks who don't have the requirement of making `multi` optional:

You can do that by declaring `MySelect` as a union of types, one with `multi: true` and the other with `multi: false`:

```typescript
type MySelect =
    {
        multi: true;
        onChange: (items: string[]) => void;
    }
    |
    {
        multi: false;
        onChange: (item: string) => void;
    };
```

Then you get:

```typescript
const mySelect: MySelect = {
    multi: true,
    onChange: (items) => {}
//  ^^^^^^^^−−−−−−−−−−− correctly inferred as (items: string[]) => void
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiDKEA2EDGwoF4BQU9QG9d8SBbAVyWAEsAuKYAJ3IgG5iS8B7AOwGEAFgEMeAcwj0AFNWARSAZ3rym1MQG0AugEosAPigA3LtQAm7EgF8OUAD7WinfBSp0oAMyFJ5bayV6CRcSkZOSUVMR1MfSNTc3wLdmxUXmUoUgRkNGB6OEQUdCxCa2caeiYWABprf2ExCShpWQVI-QIrAHp2vAA9Xr7ewCQiIeGRgahkxkYspBAoVTcISYgTKCF5BpCFMMZVUU0Ww2MTbATsIA)

That's called a [*discriminated union*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions): a union of types that are discriminated (told apart) by the type of one (or more) of the fields.

If you had a large set of other properties that didn't vary, you could add them to the discriminated union by using an intersection:

```typescript
type MySelect =
    (
        {
            multi: true;
            onChange: (items: string[]) => void;
        }
        |
        {
            multi: false;
            onChange: (item: string) => void;
        }
    )
    &
    {
        the:        number;
        other:      string;
        properties: string;
    };
```

Comment: Here, in my blog https://catchts.com/callbacks#callback_in_union%202 you can find how ot make distributive union type in more generic way

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that multiple is an optional argument (defaulting to false). In this case, discriminated union seems to fall short [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiDKEA2EDGwoF4BQU9QAoBvXfMgWwFclgBLALimACdKIBuUsvAewDsAwgAsAhnwDmERgVrAI5RgGcWtCQG0AugEosAPigA3HrQAmnMgF8u3AD7WS3fFRoMoAMxFJFHa2X7CxSWlZeSUVCR1MfSNTc3wLKBsoB0coZzpGSj4TCDdVCDNffH9RCSlCEIUoZWZVcUjo40LLHSSUxxLA8pk5Kpq6hsMmuLwrfE5sVH5lNIRkNGBGOEQUdCxk606y4N7FQfbuZghgSmY+KErFEagrC3YgA)

Comment: @htulipe - That was simultaneously a fairly easy thing to forget to mention and a really important thing not to forget to mention.  I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using a generic identity function:

```
function helper<T extends boolean>(obj: MySelect<T>): MySelect<T> {
    return obj;
}

// MySelect<true> inferred
const mySelect = helper({
    multi: true,
    onChange: (items) => {}
});
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8DKEA2EFgA8AKshAB6QgAmAzsgEYD2TecIAfMgN4BQyA5AFsArjjDAAXMmIAafoKYgAwgAt2AcwjSAFMEhDppClTrIwUESgD8yWhdAaA2gF1p9qI4CUyALxcANyZgal4AX15eGBEQAmAlZFVcAAdoEjJKCBp6ZlYIdg4dJgYAK2kMbDwCEg4vcqxcfCJiLj5BZCgIMBEoEGRikoBucMiAelG0BqqiCysuUBhoTtCEJXthKaa-RJToHTbBUXEpc0sIeXalNU1tZD0DWh9-Hgiwr2GgA)

That said, this technique is more useful when your type parameter doesn't have a finite set of distinct options; in your case, `T extends boolean` is probably better implemented as a tagged union type as in T.J. Crowder's answer, without generics.